# Management API : How to create User ID Enabled Property / View

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

How can I create Property / View with User ID enabled?

I'm looking at [Web properties parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties) ref. but dint find any parameter related with `userId`.

Also queried a User ID enabled Property / View (using get) but the API response has no such `userID` parameter []

Thanks for any clue!

Answer (score 0):

The user id field in Google analytics is used for internal proccesing like the session id there is no dimension for requesting this dimension out of the API.

if you need it you should look into adding it as a custom dimension.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Does that also mean we can't enable GA Property for User IF feature, and neither we can create USER ID GA View? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand that.   you can't add userid to the report in GA or via the API unless you add it as a custom dimension

Comment: Just for clarification: I'm NOT talking about core reporting API. The OQ was re: Management API. I want to create a new GA Property / View with User ID feature enabled. Thanks!